# Since electrons travel from negative pole, do signals reach components closer to negative pole first?

Tags: current

If transmission line effects are minimized (the circuit is something like a circle for example, as seen below), and, since electrons travel from negative to positive, does a signal tend to reach components closer to the negative pole first? For example, if there are three circuits, with a "signal measurement device" placed either 1/4th from the negative pole, or 1/4th the distance from the positive, or half way in between, will the circuit with the measurement device closest to the negative pole receive the signal first? And if yes, is this easily tested and have there been any good experiments historically to demonstrate the effect?

[image]
*Source: top - Andre Koch Torres Assis, Julio Akashi Hernandes, "The Electric Force of a Current, figure 2.3, page 25*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145998/discussion-on-question-by-bipedaljoe-since-electrons-travel-from-negative-pole); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Typical [electron drift velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity#Numerical_example) are minuscule compared to the speed of light -- or for that matter, compared to a walking pace.

If there is any trend for "signals arriving first to components" at one "pole" or another it is entirely due to electrodynamic effects that treat charge as a massless fluid, not to the physics of individual electrons.

Electrons do mediate the propagation of the electric field in the vicinity of a conductor, but it's because they act like a fluid, not because individual electrons carry the field.

> If transmission line effects are minimized (the circuit is something like a circle for example).

I'm not sure what you're thinking there, but if the signal is being carried by wires or other classical conductors, it's *all* electrodynamic effects, of which transmission line effects are just a subset.  It may be obscure, and there may be some antenna effects mixed in, but it's electrodynamic.  So even if you arrange the circuit in a circle or other shape, the signal propagation can still be calculated using electrodynamics and ignoring the electron drift velocity.

The only time that I know of where electron transport makes the kind of difference you're talking about is when there is a literal electron beam in a vacuum.

If you're into antique electronics you'll know that tube amplifers started hitting electron-speed limits in the 1920's or 1930's and the hundreds of megahertz.  This discovery was shortly followed by a range of different special tube types for VHF and higher amplification.  A of these either feature super-short dimensions to push the "normal" operating frequency higher, or they use electron-transport effects to the same end.

In a sense, your question doesn't make sense because of the requirement to minimize or eliminate transmission line effects.  If you're talking about time-of arrival of electronic signals, then -- in the absence of actual charge carriers in a vacuum -- it's *all* classical electrodynamic effects.  Any effort to minimize or eliminate *transmission line effects* specifically will just lead to arguments about where transmission lines end and antenna effects or other free-space transmission of energy begins -- which is why I keep citing electrodynamics in general, rather than trying to make distinctions about what is or is not a "transmission line effect".

So, no -- the polarity of the charge carrier doesn't make a difference in normal circumstances.  Where there *is* a difference it's in the case of carriers in a vacuum, or the Hall effect, and neither of these are relevant to your question.

Comment: I'm aware electron drift velocities are miniscule compared to the speed of light. And that they act like a fluid. Re: transmission line effects, if you look at the first comment on this question, someone mentioned a youtube video. I clarified to avoid that. In that video, capacitance between wires forms a circuit, so why I mentioned a circular circuit. I do not feel like you really answered the question. The only way it would not merit an answer, is if there is no trend for signal arriving first to components closer to either pole (or half way), but I don't think you claimed that either.

Comment: Your "transmission line effects" is just a subset of classical electrodynamics -- which I stated (and just clarified further).  **It's all classical electrodynamics**.  Sorry -- that's just the way it is.  You're not arguing with **me**, you're arguing with a whole lot of dead physicists, both credited in the literature and not.  If it weren't true, then just about every high-speed electronics circuit in the entire world would act differently than it actually does, and circuit designers would have an entirely different set of rules for designing them successfully.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. I just explained why I phrased my question the way I did, and it is corroborated by the first comment on it. I did not mean to be rude, or insulting, or dismissive. I simply wonder if there is a trend for a signal to arrive first to components closer either pole. From my point of view, it does not seem like a strange question. I am very open to that I am uneducated and miss something fundamental, but I tend to be able to understand things and also in electronics.

Comment: @BipedalJoe It feels to me as though you are thinking in terms of what you can touch and feel (our level of observation, which is where emergent phenomena arise through large population statistics and has nothing whatever to do with the quantum level at which things actually take place in nature.) Just a quick calculation using Fermi-Dirac statistics and their distribution term, I find for example that, at 20 C, conduction band electrons experience a pressure exceeding 3.4x10^8 pascals in an unconnected piece of copper wire. Does this fact affect any of your thoughts?

Comment: You can touch and feel anything, using the right instruments :) How would you like that fact to influence my thinking? I still think the question of if a signal tends to reach components closer to the poles (and if yes, any difference between them), before it reaches a component half way, is valid, and it seems like generalizations can be made about that.

Comment: @TimWescott If polarity does not matter, and the statement to minimize transmission line effects is dismissed, can it be generalized to that the signal in the described circuit (an image of the circuit https://i.imgur.com/J1Vcrfm.png) will reach the measurement devices closest to the poles first, and, the one half way in between last? Or is it possible to make any similar generalization at all?

Comment: > I simply wonder if there is a trend for a signal to arrive first to components closer either pole.  -- It might help us if you would explain *why* you would ask this question? What thinking led to it?  (The usual reason is that, in grade-school, we're all taught that electrons individually carry the energy, that wires act like hollow pipes, and the electrons zoom through the wires at lightspeed.   In that case, OF COURSE the signal arrives sooner from the negative pole.   But every part of that K12-grade explanation is wrong.)

Comment: hi William, I had it answered already by sredni vashtar, the component half way receives the signal last

Answer (score 3):

There is no polarity dependence.  If there were, most systems would be magically nonlinear, and that does not fit observations.

Probably the easiest reason to see why most systems are linear, is because there is an extraordinary concentration of electrons.  Even in insulators, the free electron concentration is numerically large (say, millions per cm<sup>3</sup>; electrons are vanishingly small, so this isn't actually a very interesting observation), but in metals it's unimaginable (~10<sup>26</sup> per cm<sup>3</sup>).  Most circuits are not governed by the presence or absence of electrons, or of other particles, but an extremely minuscule difference in astronomical concentrations of electrons.

That is, just on the surface of a metal, there might be, say, 10<sup>15</sup> electrons, normally.  A one volt difference between adjacent conductors say 1cm apart, might be an excess or absence of merely 10<sup>6</sup> electrons, or one part per billion.  And only at the surface; the effect does not extend into the bulk.

So it's essentially impossible to observe such an effect in metals.

Indeed, the concentration balance remains, even up to more or less the breaking point of the metal.  You can't sink enough current through, or drop enough voltage across, a metal to observe a difference, at least until it ceases to be metal anymore (i.e. because you've turned it to plasma).

Anyway, the propagation velocity is hardly defined by the conductor itself.  Rather it's the dielectric filling the space around it.  However, the same argument applies, though for spontaneously-polarizable dipoles rather than electrons.

Semiconductors, having lower concentrations of charge carriers (and not necessarily using electrons as such), can observe charge-dependent effects.  A nonlinear transmission line for example can have higher velocity under positive bias; these aren't very helpful for the most part, but can be used to generate electromagnetic shock waves (which isn't quite as exciting as it sounds).

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the signal originates; it’s not like the wires are empty and some electrons are introduced, but rather t that the electrons are present all the time and an electrical field causes them to move.  The effect of this propagates from the point or area of origin; in copper this is about half the speed of light in a vacuum.  On PC motherboards you’ll se wiggles in some tracks to ensure that the lengths are matched, one could also use different lengths to create timing skew, e.g. using a longer tracks for a clock line to give signals some time to settle before they are latched.

Comment: I know you can delay a signal by making longer traces. And I'm aware the wire "has electrons in it", if it is copper then those copper atoms "have electrons". I do not see that you address the question really though.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ‘negative pole’.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that can be misunderstood. But of course I can clarify, it that is desired. The pole electrons originate from.

Comment: In the sense of the power supply or the component that’s switching the signal?

Comment: In the sense of the power supply, is what I meant. What the term usually means in similar context. But, in the component receiving the signal, it is the same thing. The "negative pole" of a transistor would be the emitter, that is connected to the negative pole of the power supply. Right. But if it is desired that I clarify, I will of course.

Comment: The signal will propagate from the component where the switching occurs, not from the power supply.  It will propagate both towards the negative supply (with a lowering of electron density and more electrons moving out of the negative supply) and towards the positive supply, with surplus electrons moving towards the positive supply.  The propagation delay is easily measurable with suitable equipment and is about 1ns per 150-200mm of conductor.

Comment: For simplicity, I was thinking power supply could be considered the signal. I mean, we can add an extra step, but the result should be the same as far as I can see. I know propagation delay is easily measured. Thus it should be easy to know if signal tends to arrive faster to components closer to either pole, or, if the components are half way between. But I don't know the answer to that, so I thought I'd ask here, because I'm interested in the answer to it.

Comment: The signal starts to propagate from the point in the circuit where the switching occurs, a transistor in this case.  The power supply won’t ‘know’ that this has happened until the signal propagates to it.

Comment: hi my intention with the question was to assume power supply as signal but some other component can also be assumed. i had it answered to me by sredni vashtar. thanks for your input, peace

Comment: @BipedalJoe power signal, voltage signal or current signal: none can exist in any place without the other. Frog's statements hence fully apply! The signal(s) propagate from the switch, and the supply "observes" them no earlier than anything else connected by the same geometry of conductor.

Comment: hi, as mentioned i was thinking the power supply could be the switch (as in when it is plugged in). but I have had the question answered by shredni vashtar as also mentioned. you closed the earlier question I asked, but it was answered this time.